# How can i check if a string matches String array

Tags: java, string, arraylist

How can i check if a string matches any of elements in string array.

Suppose a String array contain {abcdef, ghijkl}
 Comparing it with a string "abc" should return the first value

If have been using `stringArray.contains(string)` method but it seems to work only if the complete string matches. I need to get the result even if the string partially matches

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: loop it and check contains by each of the elements?

Comment: I appreciate the quick accept!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Streams come in handy:

```
Arrays.stream(stringArray)
  .filter(s -> s.contains(stringToSearch))
  .findFirst();
```

Of course, your requirements boil down to: find the first string in the array that *starts* with the search string. But actually your requirements are a bit unclear, so you should apply the filter as required. There is a big difference between `contains()` and `startsWith()` for example!

Answer (score 2):

No method without using a loop. I understand you might be looking for some implementation which does not need a self written loop. But you have to loop.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `indexOf` method:

```
String[] contains(String[] stringArray, String target) {
    String[] result = new String[2];

    for(int index = 0; index < stringArray.length; index++) {
        String current = stringArray[index];
        if (s.indexOf(target) >= 0) {
            result[0] = current;
            result[1] = String.valueOf(index);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can i also get the position in stringArray on which the match is found

Comment: You can use a String[] represents the result. result[0] holds the String, result[1] holds the position.

Comment: @jpsingh The most efficient way to thank someone who answers you on Stack Overflow is by accepting his answer by click on the check mark button. Accept this answer if this solved your problem.